# .Net Core 3.1 built-in Angular SPA Template Customize Login/Register Template

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, single-page-application

How to change template for login register and other auth pages! there is no documentation.

**you can try this**

```
dotnet new angular --auth individual
```

here is the screenshot[image: ul]

and folder structure untouched. where is the auth page login page etc?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use .net core CLI if not using visual studio  :

1. Create project using template : `dotnet new angular --auth Individual` and build the project .
2. If you have not previously installed the ASP.NET Core scaffolder, install it in terminal in vs code :

   `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`
3. Add required NuGet package references to the project :

   `dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`

   `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
4. You can list the files that can be scaffolded with `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles`
5. Run the Identity scaffolder with the options you want , use `--files` to scaffold specific files ,use the correct fully qualified name for your DB context:

   `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc ProjectName.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login"`

   If you run the Identity scaffolder without specifying the `--files` flag or the `--useDefaultUI` flag, all the available Identity UI pages will be created in your project.

Now if you want to modify the login UI , you can modify relevant page in `your project --> Areas-->Identity -->Pages-->Account -->Login.cshtml` page .

Comment: thanks but i need spa side template. not backend or server side

Comment: That template uses asp.net core identity to manage users . You need to login user in client side ? Then you can't use the default template , you will need to use resource owner flow to collect user's credential in client  which should be avoid for security reasons  .

Comment: I would suggest keeping using asp.net core identity  and use the default data access approach with Sql Server and Entity Framework Core handling persistence. A further benefit of this setup is that the Identity system plugs nicely into IdentityServer to provide user profile and claims data which we'll see shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Affter the my large investigation for Scaffold Identity in CLI in Vs Code using dotnet aspnet-codegenerator. I haved many problems for the recent versions of .Net Core in ubuntu. Then Im take the radical decition for the genearte Scaffold Identity on Microsonft Visual Studio 2019 Installing a virtual Machine for Windows 10.
Affter I make commit in my git reopository and then open the project in Visual Studio Code.
In conclution this is was the solution if you want Customize Login/Register Template in CLI

[enter image solution here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YxTH.png)